# Flash suddenly stopped working in SeaMonkey / Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: flash, seamonkey

Somehow flash just stopped working in SeaMonkey. It has version 11.2.202.291 which is relatively recent, and was working until a few days ago (I do not know exactly when it stopped working.)

Firefox gets its version from /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so and that one works just fine. However, if I try to use that version with SeaMonkey, it doesn't even get detected...

Also, I clicked on the link

> Find updates for installed plugins at mozilla.com/plugincheck

and the plugin is shown as current / valid.

Any idea what would be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! I had the 32 bit version because a while back the 64 bit version of SeaMonkey would crash all the time. I tried to run the stock 64 bit version of SeaMonkey and it crashed over and over again but I had the time to see that it was version 2.0.1. I guess no one bothered updating that crashing version. Oh well...

I went to Mozilla and downloaded the latest (2.5.x) and installed that 64 bit version. That works like a charm! Not only is it capable to use the same Flash binary than Firefox, but that way I have access to all sorts of plugins, way more than before.

Note that in the process I lost all my bookmarks, but the files from the 32 bit version were still available so all I had to do is load them and I got my bookmarks back. To load those, you have to go in your ~/.mozilla folder, then find the "default" directory for SeaMonkey. It should be fairly easy to find.